# Код группы ВКонтакте не расширяется на 100%

Tags: html, css, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Разместил на своём сайте код своей группы ВКонтакте, но она не расширяется на 100% как мне хотелось бы. Как быть?

Comment: Непонятно, о каком коде речь и откуда, дополните вопрос

Comment: У виджетов вк в поле формирования кода для подключения виджета, есть поле `Ширина` - установи 100%

Comment: Код можно посмотреть тут: https://vk.com/dev/Community?height=400&link=http%3A%2F%2Fvk.com%2Fsitev_ru&mode=3&no_cover=1&oid=-134279503&wide=

Comment: Да установил ширину 100%, но не работает. Можно посмотреть на сайте sitev.ru слева

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В полученном скрипте укажите width: auto

Пример ниже

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?160"></script>

<!-- VK Widget -->
<div id="vk_groups"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {mode: 3, width: "auto"}, 134279503);
</script>
```

Comment: и у #vk_groups тоже ширина 100% соответственно должна быть